# Concurrent jobs SQL: what does it mean

Tags: mysql

How to define concurrent jobs in MySQL to get the avg number of concurrent jobs? Don't even quite understand what this means. The dataset is job_id, start_time, end_time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should first get records which start_time are the same and get total,then do the avg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).